# manipulation docx for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ms-word, docx

I want to manipulate docx files in wp7,c#. In windows I always use : http://docx.codeplex.com/ but it can't be added as a reference to a wp7 project.
Is there any control or alternative dll? Or is there any simple documentation about making doxc file? I read msdn documentation and I just got confused!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a library for editing docx files for WP7 / Silverlight. However, the DocX library you link to is only dependant on the ./NET 4.0 framework. As DocX is most likely composed of non-UI code, there is a good chance that if you place the code into a WP7 Silverlight class library, you will be able to compile it.

Comment: docx has used some assemblies that don.t exist in wp7

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

Comment: System, System.Collections.Generic, System.Linq, System.Xml.Linq are all present in WP7. You are going to have to do some work yourself to resolve the other issues!

Comment: thank you. But i think changing the code in order to work without any of these assemblies is as hard as making new project from scratch;)

Answer (score 0):

Independentsoft has set of Office APIs compiled as Portable Class Library. It works on Silverlight, Windows Phone 7/8 and .NET Windows Store Apps.